# Hide and Show list items in menu in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu where I have all the items in `li`s. What I want to do is whenever the `li`s are more than 5 I want to display "view more" option and hide the remaining `li`s and show them on click of "view more" and hide them reverse when another "view more" of `li` is clicked

this is my html

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Categorys</a>
        <div>
            <ul> <a href=""> title="This is an example of a caption"></a></ul>
            <ul>
                <h3>Title1</h3>
                <li data-bind="100002"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100028"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <h3>Title2</h3>
                <li data-bind="100000"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100004"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100007"><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100009"><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100010"><a href="#">5</a></li>//hide from here and show view more option and show them on click
                <li data-bind="100011"><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100051"><a href="#">7</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                 <h3>Title3</h3>
                <li data-bind="100103"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100105"><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li data-bind="100115"><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200071"><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200072"><a href="#">5</a></li>//hide from here and show view more option and show them on click
                <li data-bind="200073"><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200043"><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200044"><a href="#">8</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200045"><a href="#">9</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200046"><a href="#">10</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200047"><a href="#">11</a></li>
                <li data-bind="200048"><a href="#">12</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is a jsfiddle of what I am trying to do:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qN59g/)

When the `li`s are not more than 5 the "view more" option should not be there,and the "view more" option should be replaced with less and on click of that those should be hidden are if I go to other "view more" and click that the opened one should be closed.

Comment: You should try on your own first..

Comment: post what u try in javascript/jquery

Comment: start a jsfiddle and get back to us on what you've tried before posting!

Comment: @BenSewards here is the fiddle of what i am doing

Comment: @TamilSelvan here is the fiddle of what i am doing

Comment: Any reason why you are using jQuery 1.6.4?

Comment: @Dom No particualr reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your jsfiddle, I did the following:

```
$('.nav li > div > ul')
  .find('li:gt(4)') //you want :gt(4) since index starts at 0 and H3 is not in LI
  .hide()
  .end()
  .each(function(){
      if($(this).children('li').length > 5){ //iterates over each UL and if they have 5+ LIs then adds Show More...
          $(this).append(
              $('<li>Show More...</li>')
              .addClass('showMore')
              .click(function(){
                  $(this).hide().siblings(':hidden').show();
                  $('.showMore').not(this).show().siblings('li:gt(4)').hide();
              })
          );
     }
  });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/qN59g/4/

Hope this helps!

***UPDATE***

```
$('.nav li > div > ul')
  .find('li:gt(4)') //you want :gt(4) since index starts at 0 and H3 is not in LI
  .hide()
  .end()
  .each(function(){
      if($(this).children('li').length > 5){ //iterates over each UL and if they have 5+ LIs then adds Show More...
          $(this).append(
              $('<li>Show More...</li>')
              .addClass('showMore')
              .click(function(){
                  if($(this).siblings(':hidden').length > 0){
                      $(this).html('Show Less...').siblings(':hidden').show();
                  }else{
                      $(this).html('Show More...').show().siblings('li:gt(4)').hide();
                  }
              })
          );
     }
  });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/qN59g/6/

Comment: you are removing the show more option when i click on the other rather it should be there but the opened lis should be hidden and i want to show less option for opende li on click of viewmore

Comment: Wait, so you want there to be a "Show Less" option?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Make sure to add that "Show Less" feature in your question. I went based on your jsfiddle example, where you remove the "Show More" option, so I assumed you did not want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var viewMore = $('<li class="viewmore">Show More...</li>');
var nav = $('ul.nav>li>div>ul');
// only append to those needed
nav.find('>li:gt(4)').hide().parent().append(viewMore);
nav.find('.viewmore').click(function () {
    //hide all outside the limit
    nav.find('>li:gt(4)').hide();
    //show the viewmore - all or them
    nav.find('.viewmore').show();
    // now hide the viewmore and show its siblings
     $(this).hide().siblings().show();
});
```

EDIT NOTE: the above works, but it IS sequence sensitive.  IF you can use more recent jQuery, use the `.on()` like so:

```
var viewMore = $('<li class="viewmore">Show More...</li>');
var nav = $('ul.nav>li>div>ul');
nav.find('>li:gt(4)').hide().parent().append(viewMore);
nav.on('click','.viewmore',function () {
    nav.find('>li:gt(4)').hide();
    nav.find('.viewmore').show();
    $(this).hide().siblings().show();
});
```